# spotify-web-api-node WebapiError

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, spotify

I am using [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) on my react application and I am trying to do an api call via it's built in function.

Basically I have keys.js file where I put all of my config:

```
module.exports = {
  clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  redirectURI: "http://localhost:8080/callback"
};
```

And then on my react I've put the ff:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
const config = require("../../config/keys");

// credentials are optional
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: `${config.clientId}`,
  clientSecret: `${config.clientSecret}`,
  redirectUri: `${config.redirectURI}`
});

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Search tracks whose name, album or artist contains 'Love'
    spotifyApi.searchTracks("Love").then(
      function(data) {
        console.log('Search by "Love"', data.body);
      },
      function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
         <h2>TEST</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

So as you can see, I carefully followed the steps by first putting this:

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");

// credentials are optional
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: `${config.clientId}`,
  clientSecret: `${config.clientSecret}`,
  redirectUri: `${config.redirectURI}`
});
```

And then by inside the componentDidMount I tried to do a searchTrack and console.log the result to check if I am pulling the data properly:

```
componentDidMount() {
        // Search tracks whose name, album or artist contains 'Love'
        spotifyApi.searchTracks("Love").then(
          function(data) {
            console.log('Search by "Love"', data.body);
          },
          function(err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        );
      }
```

But instead of having all the data result back, I got:

```
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
    index.jsx:55 

WebapiErrormessage: "Unsuccessful HTTP response"name: "WebapiError"statusCode: 401__proto__: Object
    (anonymous) @ index.jsx:55
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong why I can't pull up the data properly?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I've got the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here